# How to implement multiple settings views that only vary wrt. data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wondering how I should implement a multi-faceted account settings UI in ASP.NET MVC 4, i.e., there's one view for each settings facet (e.g. General settings, Email addresses...), that you navigate between with the help of a tab bar. Each settings view would share the same layout and only differ in terms of data, i.e., each view has a form with different fields.

These mockups should illustrate what I mean:

[image: Generalk settings]
[image: Email settings]

To elaborate, what's the most efficient (DRY) way of generating these views with ASP.NET MVC 4? As you can see the views are constructed in the same way, and vary only in terms of the title and the fields of the form. There must be some simple way of re-using the common structure in the views, and simply specialize it for each of them, but I'm not sure how to do it.

### The Solution

flem's answer put me on the right track, but I revised it a little bit, in particular by making the settings layout nested.

Settings layout:

```
@model SettingsModelBase
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  ViewBag.Title = string.Format("Settings - {0}", ViewBag.SettingsSection);
}

<h1>@Model.SelectedPage.ToString()</h1>
<div class="account-section">
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @RenderBody()
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
  }
</div>
```

Personal settings view:

```
@model PersonalSettingsModel
@{
  Layout = "_SettingsLayout.cshtml";
  ViewBag.SettingsSection = "Account";
}

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev See my edited question, I've elaborated on what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you tried using layours/master pages? Are your tabs processed server-side or client-side?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I haven't tried anything in particular yet, since I'm not sure which approach to take. I've been wondering if a common "settings" layout would be a start. The tabs are processed server-side, i.e. they link to each view.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev You think a "settings" layout would be the right approach here? I haven't written nested layouts before, only for the whole site.

Comment: I don't see why you can't start with layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a custom layout for settings pages and a model for each settings view, each extending the same base class. Something like this (note that I haven't tested this code - it's freehand):

Base Model:

```
public abstract class SettingsModelBase
{
    public SettingsPageEnum SelectedPage { get; set; }
}
```

Personal details settings model:

```
public class PersonalSettingsModel : SettingsModelBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model PersonalSettingsModel
@{
    Layout = "SettingsLayout.cshtml";
}
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Layout:

```
@model SettingsModelBase

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        @Model.SelectedPage.ToString()
        <div id="settingsdiv">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, will give a shot and get back to you!

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to reflect how I worked it out, by using a nested layout (so that I have a top-level site layout, and a nested settings layout).

Comment: @aknuds1 I rejected your edit, because it was quite a radical change.It is great that you post feedback here about how you solved your question, but better add it as an answer on its own.

Comment: @Marijn OK, wasn't entirely sure if it were better to post a new answer or revise this answer which put me on the right track. I'll add info to my question on how I revised the solution.

Comment: Updating your question is fine too; just as answering your own question.

Comment: @Marijn I figured it was better to not add an extra answer, considering I accepted this. Others might not notice it.